Error: (1) no such table: person in "SELECT * FROM person"
I am making a mobile application with the sqlite database, but I get an error when trying to read the "person" table, the database is connected correctly, and the table has data.
class Main Activity
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnShowBD = findViewById(R.id.btnShowBD);
        listBD = findViewById(R.id.listBD);

        bdHelper = new BDHelper(this);

        try {
            database = bdHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public void onClickBtnShowBD(View view) {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<String, String> person;

        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM person", null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                person = new HashMap<>();
                person.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
                person.put("achievement", cursor.getString(2));
                persons.add(person);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, persons, R.layout.listview_item,
                new String[]{"name", "achievement"},
                new int[]{R.id.textPerson, R.id.textAchievement});
        listBD.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

class BDHelper
public BDHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, BD_NAME, null, BD_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
        BD_LOCATION = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";

        copyBD();
    }

    private boolean checkBD() {
        File fileBD = new File(BD_LOCATION + BD_NAME);
        return fileBD.exists();
    }

    private void copyBD() {
        if (!checkBD()) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyBDFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void copyBDFile() throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = myContext.getAssets().open(BD_NAME);
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(BD_LOCATION + BD_NAME);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

Error
(1) no such table: person in "SELECT * FROM person"
I was checking the logs to see if the database is connected, that's not the error. The browser for SQLite also has a table, the database itself lies in assets

Put your schema name on your query, for grins.  select * from my_schema.person
